# Show that if $f \sim^{\mathcal{R}} g$, then $\text{ord } (f) = \text{ord } (g)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-homomorphism, singularity-theory, polynomial-rings

> **Problem:** Let $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[[\mathrm{x}]] = \mathbb{C}[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$. Show that if $f \sim^{\mathcal{R}} g$ then $\text{ord } (f) = \text{ord } (g)$.

**My attempt:** Follow the definition, we have $f \sim^{\mathcal{R}} g$ if there exists a $\mathbb C$-algebra isomorphism  $\varphi \colon \mathbb{C}[[\mathrm{x}]] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[[\mathrm{x}]]$ such that $\varphi(f) = g$. Furthermore, suppose $\text{ord}(f) = b$. We have $g$ is $x_n$-general of order $b$, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism so $\text{ord} (g) = b$.

Is my proof correct? Thank all!

Comment: What does it mean to be $k$-general? What does "order $f \sim^{\mathcal R} g$" mean?

Comment: What does "ord" mean?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Let $f = \displaystyle\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n} a_{\alpha} x^{\alpha}, f \ne 0$ then $\text{ord} (f) = \min \{ |\alpha|, a_{\alpha} \ne 0 \}$.